# What is the difference in using strained or non-strained almond milk for pancakes?

Tags: vegan, pancakes, almond-milk

My main aim is to make a cream out of almond milk, which I could fold into a vegan pancake batter.

I typically work with two types of almond milk. One type is "watery" and is made of grinding almonds with water and filtering the liquid and a second type is "creamy" and is made of mixing almond paste (almond butter) with water.

How do those liquids differ when using them for making pancakes?

Comment: Hi, I am afraid your question is unanswerable as stated. Distinctions aren't true or untrue, they are useful or not useful - in regard to a purpose. "How does A differ from B" - there are tons of correct (and usually uninteresting) answers for that for any A and B. If you explain your purpose of comparing the two types of milk, we can reopen the question and tell you how they differ in regard to that purpose (as long as it is a culinary one, since that is our site scope). There is an "edit" link under your post to expand on what you are comparing the milks for.

Comment: Tahini is sesame paste, not almond paste.  And there are way more than two types: flavored (vanilla) vs plain, sweetened vs not, just almonds and water (what you say is watery) vs stabilized with gums, etc.

Comment: @Joe in Hebrew it's not uncommon to say טחינת שקדים as in "almond tahini" but yeah I think חמאת שקדים (almond butter) is more common.

Comment: @rumtscho does the question fit now? Please further help me out here...

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you for editing. I changed a few more formulations, to make it answerable and not impossibly generic, and reopened the question.

Comment: @Joe I can echo what Markus is saying - I am also accustomed to languages in which "tahini" is an umbrella term, like "puree", and one has to specify the nut from which the tahini is made. Although sesame is indeed rather common, so it can be left out sometimes, especially in informal situations - but you won't see just "tahini" on the supermarket shelf the way you see just "milk" for cow milk. It may be that the usage has changed when the word entered English, but I wouldn't be too surprised about people transferring their native usage to English, given that the cognate exists.

Comment: You *can* just make pancakes with self-raising flour & water. They come out a bit more like roti, but they work. i'd rather have one of those than one with 'fake' milk.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is the amount of solids and fats. What you prefer should be up to your taste (personally I like creamy versions of milk alternatives). However, you should note, that the amount of solids and fats will either lead to a different dough result or some thought on how to balance this with the other ingredients for a consistent result.

Imagine it in the extreme way: You've got a finished pancake dough and now you're stirring in almond butter. It may taste really good, but it will thicken your dough and make it somewhat fattier. Therefore the pancake will have a tendency to be thicker, more filling and drier than in the case of not adding the almond butter.